# Massless ladder against a frictionless wall

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, equilibrium

I am confused by a review problem for my physics course. I keep getting a different answer from the solution (which was given to us) and not sure what I am missing.

A massless ladder has a length of $L$, and has a mass of $m$ one third of the way up, and a mass $2m$ two thirds of the way up. It leans against a frictionless wall. The feet of the ladder have a coefficient of static friction $\mu_s=0.6$ with the ground. What is the largest angle $\theta$ the ladder can make with the wall?

So far, I drew this diagram of the problem (sorry its ugly :)), and have worked out the following:
[image: Free Body Diagram]

- $\sum F_y = 0 = F_n - mg - 2mg$
- $\sum F_x = 0 = F_w - F_f$
- $\sum \tau = 0 = (2mg)(\frac{2}{3}Lsin\theta) + (mg)(\frac{1}{3}Lsin\theta) - (F_w)(Lcos\theta) $
- $F_f = F_w = \mu_s F_n $ (since concerned with point where it slips)

After some maths using net torque I get:

$\frac{sin\theta}{cos\theta} = \frac{9*3}{5*5} $

$\theta = arctan(\frac{27}{25}) = 47.2^\circ $

The answer is supposed to be $\theta = 19.8^\circ$ but I keep getting $\theta = 47.2^\circ$ and I am not sure what I am missing or messing up.

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe I'm missing something but I don't see anything wrong with your derivation or answer, either.

Comment: I'm not sure if the supposedly correct answer of 19.8˚ passes the sniff test. A common rule when using a ladder is that one should put the ladder at an angle such that if the base of the ladder is at your feet then you should be able to hold the ladder at shoulder height at arm's length. That works out to an angle of about 20˚. My ladder has rubber feet on a concrete garage floor. The coefficient of friction of rubber on concrete is about 0.6 to 0.8. According to the official answer to this problem of 19.8˚, my ladder should be on the threshold of slipping, and I don't believe that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really worked it out, but my first impression is that in your torque equation the Fw term should be cos(90-theta) not cos(theta).  See if that helps.